# yii2 how to run console controller function

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm stuck. I'm trying to run some function from the command shell.
I'm using the HelloController from the basic project.
When I run `php yii hello` it's working good and the index function is running but if I try to run different function like `php yii hello/create` I'm getting this error -

> Error: Unknown command.

I added the create function to this controller.
The strange thing is that when I run `php yii` I'm seeing the create command.
My controller code

```
namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
use Yii;

class HelloController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex($message = 'hello world')
    {
        echo $message . "\n";
    }
    public function actionCreate($message = 'hello world')
    {
        echo $message . "\n";
    }

}
```

**UPDATED:**
My Config file is

```
Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__) . '/tests');

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

return [
    'id' => 'basic-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log', 'gii'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ],
    'components' => [

      'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => '...',
        'username' => '...',
        'password' => '...',
        'port' => '...',
        //'encryption' => 'tls',
      ],

        ],

        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
         'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,


    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run

```
php yii hello
```

you are calling `actionIndex` of `HelloController`. This controller does not have any other actions so that is why you see the error.

The only `create` word available in clean Basic App console installation is in the `migrate` section so you can call `actionCreate` in `MigrateController` by running

```
php yii migrate/create
```

So unless you have got some custom controllers/actions there are no other options.

For all available actions run `php yii` like you did before. You can run

```
php yii help <command-name>
```

for help about selected command.

Read more about console commands in [the Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html).

Comment: i know what you said, i added the create function to this controller and then i tried to run it but still only the index function is running.

Comment: @eli Double check your controller because this code of yours works without errors. I've just checked it.

Comment: its keep telling me the error message. is it related to other things?

Comment: how do you call the create function? like this? php yii hello/create

Comment: Yes. It must be something else then. Is it clean Basic App Project?

Comment: Yes its the basic app, but I have web controllers that working good. now I tried to add console controller and I got this error.

Comment: Check for simple typos like `craete` instead of `create` and so on.

Comment: I checked and its not working for me. even if i run "php yii hello/index" I get this error. its like its cant get the name of the function, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Never give your credentials like that! I've removed them but it is still available in revision details. Consider changing them... Anyway I can not see any problems in your config file. I'm out of ideas how to help you unfortunately.

Comment: i forgot... and i change them for sure. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

it works after follow this steps

1. goto your root folder of project
2. open root folder path in terminal.
3. now my controller name is : **ContactMigrationController**
   and function name is : **actionGetContact**
4. then run this cmd **php yii contact-migration/get-contact**
5. done.

Answer (score 0):

When you call console controller from hosting, you need to know path of: PHP and YII
For example: `/usr/bin/php -q /home1/globustm/public_html/yii hello/index`

In localhost (local PC) you don't need show PHP and YII paths, because its inserted to SYSTEM PATH by default.

If you want send some parameters you need add them after action:
For example one parameter: `hello/index 'param1'`

For example if you have more than one parameter, so add them with space: `hello/index 'param1' 'param2' 'param3'`

Answer (score 0):

put your controller in the folder commands/
By the way, there is HelloController.php. Make your own controller by analogy.
Be aware:

```
namespace app\commands;
class MyController extends yii\console\Controller{}
```

run:

> php yii my/action